# Tables with the same name from different namespaces in the same context

Tags: entity-framework-core

Does anybody know whether EF Core supports two tables with the same name from different namespaces/assemblies in the same context? I have very similar scenario as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f08158b9-e554-467c-89c3-1c5104177d4c/how-to-fluently-map-a-class-and-its-inherited-properties-but-ignore-the-ancestor-class-with-the?forum=adodotnetentityframework) which is not supported in EF 6.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge.  Personally I would have two contexts, std & custom (using your example).  std uses person, custom uses customperson class but in your code still reference the same table name like so.

```
public DbSet<person> Persons { get; set; }
```

-or-

```
public DbSet<customperson> Persons { get; set; }
```

Most of your code would go unchanged, i.e.

```
myContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == myId);
```

and only use custom code where you are mapping or need the "extra" fields.

```
var person = myContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == myId);
if (person != null && person.HasProperty("myfield"))
    // reference myfield
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution with inheritance as described in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance).
There is an example showing a simple inheritance scenario and the data stored in a relational database table using the  table-per-hierarchy pattern. The Discriminator column identifies which type of Blog is stored in each row. Our projects looks as follows:

[image]

**BaseContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace Base.Data
{
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext()
    {
    }

    public BaseContext(DbContextOptions<BaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Tab1> Tab1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS2017;Database=base;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.Col1).HasMaxLength(50);
        });
    }
}
}
```

**ExtendedContext.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Base.Data;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal;
namespace Extended.Data
{
    public partial class ExtendedContext : BaseContext
{
    protected static DbContextOptions<T> ChangeOptionsType<T>(DbContextOptions options) where T : DbContext
    {
        var sqlExt = options.Extensions.FirstOrDefault(e => e is SqlServerOptionsExtension);

        if (sqlExt == null)
            throw (new Exception("Failed to retrieve SQL connection string for base Context"));

        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>()
                    .UseSqlServer(((SqlServerOptionsExtension)sqlExt).ConnectionString)
                    .Options;
    }

    public ExtendedContext()
    {
    }

    public ExtendedContext(DbContextOptions<ExtendedContext> options)
        : base(ExtendedContext.ChangeOptionsType<BaseContext>(options))
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Col2).HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Base.Data.Tab1>()
        .HasDiscriminator<bool>("IsExtended")
        .HasValue<Base.Data.Tab1>(false)
        .HasValue<Tab1>(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab2>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Tab1)
        .WithMany(b => b.Tab2)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.Tab1Id)
        .HasConstraintName("ForeignKey_Tab1_Tab2");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tab2>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.Col1).HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");
        });
    }

    public new virtual DbSet<Tab1> Tab1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tab2> Tab2 { get; set; }
}
}
```